# Using sed to remove all lines between two patters if text is found between them

Tags: linux, bash, text, sed

I have a file

```
###
A
B
C
@@@
###
D
E
F
@@@
###
G
H
I
@@@
```

I want to remove all lines between ### and @@@ (inclusive) if it contains A

How can I achieve this ?

expected result

```
###
D
E
F
@@@
###
G
H
I
@@@
```

I have tried

`sed "/###/,/@@@/d"`

but that is removing everything.

If we can have multiple text patterns like remove everything between ### and @@@ if it contains either 'A' or 'D' would be even helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```bash
sed '/###/{:a;N;/@@@/!ba;/A/d}' file
```

*Details*:

- `/###/` - looks for a `###` and once it is found,
- `:a` - set `a` label at the current location
- `N` - reads the next line appending it to pattern space
- `/@@@/!ba` - if there is `@@@` stop processing block, else, go to `a` label
- `/A/d` - if `A` is inside the block matched, delete it.

See an [online test](https://ideone.com/Rg5ukK):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
text=$(echo -e '###\nA\nB\nC\n@@@\n###\nD\nE\nF\n@@@\n###\nG\nH\nI\n@@@')
sed '/###/{:a;N;/@@@/!ba;/A/d}' <<< "$text"
```

Output:

```
###
D
E
F
@@@
###
G
H
I
@@@
```

Comment: Works, Thanks. Just for the case of learning how can we negate this expression, if A is found keep it and delete if not found.

Comment: @user9082746 It is done using `!` to negate the action: `sed '/###/{:a;N;/@@@/!ba;/A/!d}' file`, or we can just print the blocks with `A` using `sed -n '/###/{:a;N;/@@@/!ba;/A/p}' file`

Answer (score 2):

In case you are ok with `awk` please try following solution. Using GNU `awk` here.

```
awk -v RS="" '
{
  while(match($0,/(#[^@]*)(@+)/,arr)){
    if(arr[1]!~/\nA\n/){
       print arr[1] arr[2]
    }
    $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
  }
}
' Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

sed is great for simple substitutions on individual lines but if you find yourself trying to use more than the s, g, and p (with -n) commands then you're almost certainly better off using awk for some combination of clarity, efficiency, portability, robustness, etc.

With GNU awk for multi-char RS:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n@@@\n"} !/A/' file
###
D
E
F
@@@
###
G
H
I
@@@
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n@@@\n"} /A/' file
###
A
B
C
@@@
```

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n@@@\n"} /A|D/' file
###
A
B
C
@@@
###
D
E
F
@@@
```

or with any awk:

```
$ awk '{r=r $0 ORS} /^@@@$/{ if (r !~ /A/) printf "%s", r; r="" }' file
###
D
E
F
@@@
###
G
H
I
@@@
```

```
$ awk '{r=r $0 ORS} /^@@@$/{ if (r ~ /A/) printf "%s", r; r="" }' file
###
A
B
C
@@@
```

```
$ awk '{r=r $0 ORS} /^@@@$/{ if (r ~ /A|D/) printf "%s", r; r="" }' file
###
A
B
C
@@@
###
D
E
F
@@@
```

When A and D are single characters like above you could of course in the regexp use a set of characters in a bracket expression, `[AD]`, instead of alternation, `A|D`, in the regexp but I assume your real data isn't always single characters.

Note how trivial it is to extend that comparison to any set of "ands", "ors" or even `<`, `>`, or comparisons of lines with each other or other values from the current record or previous records as you like, e.g.:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n@@@\n"} /A/ && (/B/ || /C/) && !/D/' file
###
A
B
C
@@@
```

There's no need to test for `###` since it's always present at the start of each record, just test for the `@@@` that terminates each record.

The `\n`s or `^` and `$` anchors around `@@@` are necessary to avoid false matches when `@@@` appears in other places in your input than as a record terminator, e.g. given this input:

```
$ cat file
###
A
this is where @@@ is undesirable
C
@@@
###
D
E
F
@@@
###
G
H
I
@@@
```

The commands above will still work:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="\n@@@\n"} /A/' file
###
A
this is where @@@ is undesirable
C
@@@
```

but if we removed the anchors around `@@@` they'd incur a false match:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="@@@"} /A/' file
###
A
this is where @@@$
```